# Extension indexer for DataSet

Tags: c#, dataset, extension-methods

Is it possible to create a DataSet extension for creating a default indexer?
It may sound strange, but it would be handy if I could directly access the tables between a DataSet object like:

```
MyDataset[0].Rows....
```

Specially when you have DataWrappersWithLongNames repeatedly called along your project.

I know about the trouble of indexers being static and the trouble of the use of "this". But I'm just curious if there's an elegant solution.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand - you want to use `ds[0].Rows...` instead of the readily available `ds.Tables[0].Rows...`?

Comment: Yes. The reason is that the dataset would had a very long name and used two or three times in a statement, for example. Just curious also  for other cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create extensions for indexers or properties. Just for methods.

You could create a method called T and then it will be:

```
MyDataset.T(0).Rows
```

Which is two characters more than you wanted.

Comment: In most cases where we wanted an indexer, an extension method will logically offer the same functionality, it just wont look as pretty.