# Is it possible to create indexer in helper class c#

Tags: c#

I am intrested in creating custom indexer for `char[,]`. It seems to me that it is prohibited, but I am wondering if there is an oportunity. The code that could have solved the problem is:

```cs
public static class GeneratorHelpers
    {
        public static char int[Vector2D position] (this char[,] field)
        {
            return field[position.X, position.Y];
        }
    }
```

The above code does not compile.

Comment: Give it a try, compiler is your friend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# extend indexer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286181/c-sharp-extend-indexer) and [How to use indexers with Extension Methods having out parameter and function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117351/how-to-use-indexers-with-extension-methods-having-out-parameter-and-function-cal) and [Extension indexer for DataSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477822/extension-indexer-for-dataset) and [Does C# have extension properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619033/does-c-sharp-have-extension-properties)

Comment: @OliverRogier Thank you, they completely answer my question

Comment: @TanveerBadar the code is incorrect and was not expected to work. I've edited question in order to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no such things as extension properties, operators or indexers in the C# language. The most common pattern for this would be just to take additional parameters to an extension method.